# use update to update any one of the two tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables `user_pv` and `vendors_pv` both having same feilds.

**users_pv** => has users and their balance

**vendors_pv** => has vendors and their balance

Now i want to update balance of user or vendor based on the a value , which is obtained through some php process  . So i wrote a query like this

```
update users_pv a INNER JOIN vendors_pv b set a.Balance = a.Balance +
'240' , b.Balance = b.Balance + '40' where a.UserId = 'someid' or
b.UserId = 'someid'
```

Basically this **`someid`** value might be in any one of the table. so i need to update the user with `UserId` **`someid`**

Bu the problem here is the query is updating all the users and vendors.Please help me to solve it

**Note:** in the query i tried to replace `or` with `and` which result in updating **`0`** rows

Comment: You are missing on part of join

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid could you please explain a bit more

Comment: Ideally you would create a stored procedure to do this within a transaction.
just to give you a quick solution: join the tables via userID like update users_pv a INNER JOIN vendors_pv b on a.userid= b.userid

Comment: @krishKM the solution you provided didn't work

Comment: why dont you use two update calls?
update vendor_table set value=x where vendorid=y
update user_table set value =x where userid =y
put this in a transaction and catch erros

Comment: @krishKM i am using it in php mysqli_query. so it is not possible to call two updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update using `case` statement.
You might try this :

```
update users_pv a 
INNER JOIN vendors_pv b 
set a.Balance = 
(case when a.UserId = 'someid' then a.Balance + '240' else a.balance end) , 
b.Balance = 
(case when b.UserId = 'someid' then b.Balance + '40' else b.balance end)
```

And of course, you need to remove `where a.UserId = 'someid' or
b.UserId = 'someid'` from query.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a count to check if there is a record to be updated, based on that count you want to update only the table where the record is found.

This way you can also catch if your script decides to update non existing users.